# Why there is no exception when I cancel the token in Task.Delay?

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

I'm new to Task Parallel Library, below is my simple application:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

    var task = Task.Delay(2000, cts.Token);
    cts.Cancel();

    var exceptionProp = task.Exception;  // <------why the task's Exception is null

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

From my understanding of `Task.Delay(int millisecondsDelay, CancellationToken cancellationToken)` is, when the cancellationToken is cancelled, it will throw an `TaskCanceledException`.

But I don't understand why `exceptionProp` (task's `AggregateException` property) is null in my application, since I explicitly cancel the token, an `TaskCanceledException` should be in the `task.Exception`?

Comment: Task doesn't set `Exception` unless it's awaited or actual exception is occurred during execution. You should check `Status` property to know whether it was cancelled

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-cancellation: "*Note that this exception indicates successful cancellation instead of a faulty situation. Therefore, the task's `Exception` property returns `null`".*

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation of the [`Task.Exception`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.exception) property:

> Gets the `AggregateException` that caused the `Task` to end prematurely. If the `Task` completed successfully or has not yet thrown any exceptions, this will return null.

In your case the task has not completed successfully, but neither has failed. It has transitioned to a third completed state, which is called [`Canceled`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskstatus). When `Canceled` tasks are awaited, they throw an `OperationCanceledException`, which is the standard way of communicating cancellation in .NET. But since they are not `Faulted`, their `Exception` property is `null`.

You can check if a task is canceled by querying either its [`Status`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.status), or more easily its [`IsCanceled`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.iscanceled) property.

As a side note, in general it's not guaranteed that a `Task` will honor immediately a cancellation signal, and will transition synchronously to the `Canceled` state after calling `cts.Cancel()`. The `Task.Delay` happens to create insta-cancelable tasks, but other asynchronous methods don't. If you want to be sure that the task has completed, you must `await` it after canceling the token.

Also please note that currently the continuations of a canceled `Task.Delay` task are invoked synchronously, but most likely in the next .NET version (.NET 7) they will be invoked [asynchronously](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/pull/64217).